# Use raspberry pi as server with custom domain for django project

Tags: django, apache, dns, raspberry-pi

I found a way to set up my raspberry pi for custom domain. Than he takes the /var/www/index.html as html file. But I want it to go to my django project. I set u an apache server, but i don't realy know how to link all those. It works separate, but not togheter.

Any video or post how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Apache and django works together by the wsgi.py file, apache just runs that file when there is a request made. Here is a clear video on that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xjdv31k-Kf4

It is an hour video, but if you are just patient and follow a long for a hour, you wil leave without stress or headache :)

Comment: And of course the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/